# How to execute long javascript from stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: method in objective C?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I wanted to get all the values that user's typed in the input field of a webpage. I tried this code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    NSString *javaScript = @"var e = document.getElementsByTagName('input')for(var e in elements){if(e.type == 'text'){e.value}}";
    NSString *html = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];

    NSLog(@"test of html: %@",html);

    return YES;
}
```

Seems like it's not working:

If I know the id though:

```
javaScript = @"document.getElementById('lst-ib').value";
NSString *html = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {

    NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('input')[%d].value",i];

    NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('input')[%d].name",i];

    NSString *html = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];

    NSString *html2 = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:test];

    if (html.length > 2) {
        NSLog(@"Value %d: >>>> %@    %@",i,html,html2);
    }
}
```

This solved my query. I didn't implemented long javascript but looped the code through objective c .